# How could I have .plist path inside iPad / iPhone

Tags: ios, plist

How could I have a complete list of each .plist path (inside iPhone/iPad) ?

In iOS Simulator I'm using it : `ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.*.plist`

My goal is to find a specific key and read the boolean value in preferences.
Because I need to know if it is enable or not.

It is something that is missing in SDK but is existing in preferences.

Comment: that information is not available to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSLog (@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"/"]);`

The method returns an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the plist first. All you have to do is access it when you need it.

```
NSArray *thePlist;

NSString *plist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"plistFileName" ofType: @"plist"];
thePlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plist];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel A. White , Jahm and Kedar!

I code this to summarize each comment :

With an extra, add an example to read UISupportedInterfaceOrientations values.

```
NSLog(@"Preferences plists from apple (inside iPhone/iPad) are not accessible from code");
NSLog (@"Accessible plist paths : %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"/"]);
NSArray *pList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"/"];

for (int i = 0; i < [pList count]; i ++)
{
    NSString *plistPath = [pList objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];        
    NSMutableArray *nameString = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"];
    for (NSString *n in nameString)
    {
        NSLog(@"Supported Interface : %@",n);
    }
}
```